# Syntax error at or near "Perform" when calling a returns-void function

Tags: postgresql

Function

```
create function public.perform1(myid integer)
returns void
language 'plpgsql'
volatile security definer
as $$
begin
    delete from tbl where tblid=myid;
end;
$$;
```

Got error when calling `PERFORM` in both pgAdmin and SQL Shell:

```
perform public.perform1(123);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "perform"
LINE 1: perform public.perform1(123)
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

`SELECT public.perform1(123);` no good either:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function perform1(integer) line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`perform` is only used inside `plpgsql`. You want:

`select public.perform1(123);`

Update:

Inside the function is where you need the `perform`. I mentioned it then forgot to show it:

```
create function public.perform1(myid integer)
returns void
language 'plpgsql'
volatile security definer
as $$
begin
    perform delete from tbl where tblid=myid;
end;
$$;
```

Update 2:

Well this is will teach me to actually test code. Tested code that works:

```
create function public.perform1(myid integer)
returns void
language 'plpgsql'
volatile security definer
as $$
begin
    delete from tbl where tblid=myid;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: In my hands `perform delete from...` is also an error, unless the table has a column named "delete".  If you want to delete, just delete.  doing so only gives a 'no destination' error if the delete has a "returning" on it.  In which case the solution is to remove the "returning"

Comment: @jjanes. You are correct, my head is not screwed on tight today. New update to show correct form.